# Main content flickering when click on ionic side menu option click in Android

Tags: ionic-framework

I am facing an issue in ionic framework. Am working together Side menu bar and Tabs. When am clicking on the side menu bar to view the page. that time am facing Blinking and flickering issue in 
Here is my side menu am added in index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testing">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-                                    scalable=no, width=device-width" />
<title>tile</title>
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- <link href="css/animation.css" rel="stylesheet">  -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/controllers.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-nav-bar class=" nav-title-slide-ios7">
<ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-thin-left">
</ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view  animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-side-menu side="left">
<ion-content has-header="true" has-bouncing="true">
<ion-list class="sidemenu-bar">
<ion-item href="#/test" menu-close>test</ion-item>
<ion-item href="#/test1" menu-close>test1</ion-item>
<ion-item href="#/test2" menu-close>test2</ion-item>
<ion-item href="#/test3" menu-close>test3</ion-item>
<ion-item href="#/test4" menu-close>test4</ion-item>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
</body>
</html>

For the tabs am using my code as below.

<ion-view title="HOME" animation="slide-left-right">
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons> 
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">
<ion-tab title="tab1" icon="ion-card" href="#/tab/home" class="primartyellow">
<ion-nav-view name="home-tab" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="tab2" icon="ion-trophy" href="#/tab/tab2" class="primartyellow">
<ion-nav-view name="tab2-tab" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="tab3" icon="ion-ios-location" href="#/tab/tab3" class="primartyellow" >
<ion-nav-view name="tab3-tab" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="tab4" icon="ion-ios-heart" href="#/tab/tab4" class="primartyellow" >
<ion-nav-view name="tab4-tab" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

white flickering when click on side menu options. I have used ion bottom tabs with side menu.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well.

Comment: @YATO I have this problem, have you found a solution? When a page is not scrollable the blinking does not happen. I suppose it is related with the size of the contents but cannot find a solution for it. very frustrating as it makes the whole app not responsive...

Comment: @user3029400 Unfortunately I did not find a solution nor a workaround. I already I opened an issue on Github https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13736 . If you comment there and tell that you are experiencing the same issue they might start fixing the flickering. It would be best to comment and watch that thread instead of this 2 year thread.

Comment: @user3029400 could you upload a video so I can see your problem?